# TCL/TK Convert string to floating point and formatting the text

Tags: string, format, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm in trouble with this trivial problem. I need to read a text file with 2 column of values and write them in an output text file inside a table of 6 columns made by 8 spaces each one.

This is the input:

```
30.1843 0.167333
33.5259 0.140436
37.0905 0.2e-3
39.4298 0.0973432
```

This is what I want in the output (two possible solution: or trim the number after the 8th values, or just write them in the scientific format)

```
30.1843 0.16733  33.5259 0.14043  37.0905 0.11416
39.4298 0.09734
```

The focus of my script is:

```
set FileInput [open $filename r]

set Row 0
while {[gets $FileInput line] >= 0} { 
incr Row
                }
close $FileInput

set FileInput2     [open "Output-Table.txt"]
set Counter 0

while {$Counter <= [expr ($Row/3)]} { 

gets $FileInput2 NodeList
gets $FileInput2 NodeList2
gets $FileInput2 NodeList3

puts $Output2 "[ format "%-7s" [lindex $NodeList {0}]] [ format "%-7s" [lindex $NodeList {1}]] [ format "-7s" [lindex $NodeList2 {0}]] [format "-7s" [lindex $NodeList2 {1}]] [ format "-7s" [lindex $NodeList3 {0}]] [ format "-7s" set Sesto [lindex $NodeList3 {1}]]"

incr Counter
}
```

The first problem is that I want to use

```
 format "-7e"
```

to write numbers in a scientific format, but it makes an error.

Secondly I would like to understand why the [format "-7s"] does not work in my script. The output table, is exactly the same of the input; instead, I want to obtain at maximum 8 digits for each column.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
set f [open $filename]
set data [chan read $f]
chan close $f

set counter 0
foreach d $data {
    puts -nonewline [format { %7g} $d]
    if {[incr counter] % 6 == 0} {
        puts {}
    }
}
```

Adjust the `puts` invocations to go where you want them.

`format -7s` doesn't work because you need a percent sign to show that you want to output a value.

Documentation: [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)